# Facebook: test user cannot post to his own page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I created a page under test user account and tried to post to this page via Open Graph API ("manage_pages" is set):

https://graph.facebook.com/TEST_PAGE_ID/feed?message=Hello&access_token=TEST_USER_TOKEN

I get the following error:

{
   "error": {
      "message": "An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 2
   }
}

This works OK in two cases:

1. If I post to the page using token of another test user (not page owner).
2. If I use "real" user and "real" page.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Related: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/707203116062914/